# Cannot retrieve ACF fields from a custom plugin through get_post_meta()

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a plugin to add custom post data to the front end. I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to add custom fields to the editor.

After updating the post, I should get all custom field values via `get_post_meta()` but it is only showing the default meta fields, not the custom fields. I have two individual group fields, each with 2 text fields. I was expecting to get an array or object.

I tried to add a single text field and add data to it, just to see if the group fields are causing any problem. But no luck.

I have tried `get_field()`, `the_field()` and `get_sub_field()` functions from the ACF website but none are working.

**Edit:**
This is the code using `get_post_meta()`

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $temp = get_post_meta($post->ID);
   
    /* PRINT THE ARRAY */
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($temp);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is the code using `get_field()`

```
<?php
    $temp = get_field("field1"); // 'field1' is a one simple text field.
   
    /* PRINT THE ARRAY */
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($temp);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is the code using `the_field()`

```
<?php
    $temp = the_field("field1"); // 'field1' is a one simple text field.
   
    /* PRINT THE ARRAY */
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($temp);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is the code using `get_sub_field()`

```
<?php
    /* 'section_1' is a group consist of 2 text fields + another group with 2 
    text field. */
    $temp = the_field("section_1");
   
    /* PRINT THE ARRAY */
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($temp);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**Note:** The above code is in a file located in a sub folder of the main plugin. The thing I am trying to do is to change the layout of default blog page. In plugin's function.php I have changed the default layout path with my custom file path.

This is `function.php`

```
add_filter('single_template', 'my_custom_template', 99);

function my_custom_template($single) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)  . '/templates/style1/style1.php' ) ) {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)  . '/templates/style1/style1.php';
        }
    }

    return $single;
}
```

**Update**  When I try `var_dump(get_fields());` it returned `bool(false)`.

Comment: Show us your code. You say you tried `get_fields()`, but how did you use it after that?

Comment: i took a variable and stored the value form `get_fields()` like this `$temp = get_fields("section_title", $post->ID)`. I tried it with and without the 2nd parameter. None worked.

Comment: Edit your question to show your code. Without it, we are only guessing on what you've done.

Comment: Yes I did, just now.

Comment: I am expecting to get an array or something, but it returns null. Even get_post_meta() doesn't show any one of the custom fields.

Comment: Your code still has not been added. Just putting in the functions you've tried doesn't help. How did you use those functions? Show us some context. We can't help until we have more information.

Comment: I've run into similar issues where the functions are not hooked late enough when called from another plugin. You need to either use a later hook such as `acf/init`, or you need to use the default `get_post_meta()` function instead (bear in mind you need to prepend the group key to the subfield key for groups: https://bohanintl.com/wptips/plugins/how-to-output-data-from-acf-nested-groups/)

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. The problem seems to be solved. Today morning I just reloaded the page and it shows the meta through `get_meta_field()`. @disinfor I will still edit the code in the actual post just in case anyone needs. @Shoelaced Thanks for your answer but I already tried it yesterday but it wasn't working.

Comment: I have edited the code.. :)

Comment: That's not how you use `get_fields`. You don't pass it a field name - it returns all fields by default. Do a `var_dump(get_fields());` and let us know what it shows.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I just tried that as you said. It retured `bool(false)`.

Comment: Where did you add it, was it in the page template?

Comment: Yes, it was in the template.

Comment: And you can you get access the post in the template using `the_title`, `the_content` etc, or do you need to get the global  `$post` var first?

Comment: Yes, I can get access to those without `global $post` in the template. I still added it to the template just to be sure. And also I can get the custom field through `get_post_meta()`.

Comment: It looks like the ACF functions can't access the post, but they should be able to in you are in the loop.... just to check if that really is the problem try this: `$posttestid = get_the_ID(); echo "post id=".$posttestid; var_dump(get_fields($posttestid));` and let me know what you get!

Comment: @FluffyKitten It worked!! I feel so dumb right now, I WAS using `get_fields` but didn't even thought to put ID as the first parameter! Oh god, yesterday i was literally having headache just because of this. Anyway, Thanks for the help though @FluffyKitten  and everyone.

Comment: Glad you got sorted!  Another thing to note is that `get_field` and `the_field` also take the post id as the 2nd parameter. And also, `get_field` returns the value and `the_field` doesn't - it prints it out immediately the same as if it was echoed. I might add this as an answer, just in case someone else has the same problem as you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF fields are not saved as post meta, they use their own custom fields in the WP database. Therefore you need to use the ACF functions to get the values.

As we discussed in the comments, if you are not using the ACF functions in the Wordpress "loop", you need to pass in the post id, e.g.

```
 // post id is the 2nd parameter, but it is only needed if you are not in the loop
$fieldvalue = get_field($fieldname, $postid);
echo $fieldvalue;
```

or

```
// also note that the_field doesn't return the value like get_field -
// it prints it out just like if you used echo with get_field
the_field($fieldname, $postid);
```

For `get_fields`, it doesn't take a field parameter at all because it returns *all* fields in an array. You can pass the post id as the first parameter if you need it, e.g.

```
$allfields = get_fields($posttestid);
print_r($allfields);
```

You can see more about the [ACF functions here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#functions)